# How can I get difference between local time in millisecond and unix time in millisecond? (the shift from unixtimestamp)

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, date

I know I can convert unixTime in string format to millisecond which is in local time
`val currentTimeMillis = serverTimeDateFormat.parse(iso8601).time`

I want to know how I can get local time in millisecond for device timezone without specifing the timezone.
And when can I have local time in millisecond  I can find the difference between local and current(unix) times in millisecond as I need to have that difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can format Unix time accotding to the time zone like this:

```
long unixSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date date = new java.util.Date(unixSeconds);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
// Set time zone
sdf.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4"));
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Comment: You are converting time in millisecond to String format time but I want to get local time in millisecond without specifing location getting device location

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "local unix time". Unix timestamp is always UTC and your "system" uses a timezone parameter to display the date/time according to the given (or local or default) time zone.

If you want the "local unix time" in ms you have to add or subtract the ms according to your timezone diference to UTC.